# how to find thevenin equivalent of this circuit via source transformation?

Tags: thevenin

[image]

I can understand how it is done on the left side(150/5k and then 5k||20k then 4k*150/5k and then 4k+4k) but I just cannot figure out how to do it on the right side.

Can you please help?

Comment: What actually makes you not be able to apply the same procedures to the right side as well?

Comment: I cannot find the right order. I don't know if I should first 20||20 or 20+40 or 40x0.5 but no matter what I do I cannot find the right combination to reach the circuit below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as an aside in order to find the Thevenin equivalent of the right side you need to use source transformation for three times. First find the Thevenin equivalent of the current source and the 40k resistor. This gives you a \$V_{th}\$ and \$R_{th}\$, with \$R_{th}\$ being in series with the upper 20k resistor. The next steps would be to find the circuit equivalent of the left 20k resistor and the circuit right to it, which you've just figured it out. This involves two separate steps to finally reach the Thevenin equivalent of the right side. /end

Comment: Just a basic question. When you first find Vth and Rth by multiplying 40k resistor with current source, how do you place the 40k resistor in series with 20k resistor afterwards? In the previous problems I have solved, current source was parallel with resistor and it was on the far right/left branch of the circuit. In this example it is hard to imagine where the Rth and the Vth will end up. And that is actually why I was stuch in the first place.

Comment: Just forget the left side of the current source for a moment. Compute the Thevenin equivalent of the current source and the 40k resistor. After you figure it out, connect the equivalent you found to the rest of the circuit. In this case \$R_{th}\$ would end up being in series with the 20k resistor. Then the rest would be easy to follow.